# C delete element of an array

Tags: c, arrays

How can I delete an element of an array in c?
For example when I declare this:

```
int array[3];
```

What is in these 3 cells when I don't initialize them?

For example when I fill these now but want to delete array[2] again.

```
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 1;
array[2] = 2;
```

Now I want to delete element array[2] again.
How exactly can I do this? Setting it to 0 won't help me since this still has a meaning in my programme.

The context is, that I save the turns of a game in the array elements. But when I want to undo a turn I have to delete the element again or give that element its former "content".

Comment: answer: there's garbage. What do you mean by "deleting"? choose a value which is invalid like `-1`. You cannot "delete" `array[2]`. it's not a dynamic vector

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "delete" `array[2]` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- If it's a global or a static variable the content will be initialized to 0.
- If it's a local variable, the content will be indetermined.

---

```
int foo[3];

int Test
{
  int bar[3];
  // here the elements of bar will be indetermined

  int static blab[3];
  // here the elements of blab will be initialized to 0
}

int main()
{
  // all 3 elements of foo will be initialized to 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The contents of the array depends on where it's defined.

Global variables, or `static` local variables are zero-initialized. Local variables which are not `static` are not initialized, their values is *indeterminate* (and will *seem* random).

And there's no way to "delete" an element in an array, or make an element uninitialized. An array have a fixed size, that size can not be changed. And you can not reliably set an element to be indeterminate again (which is a state that you can not check for).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int i, size, pos;

    /* Input size and element in array */
    printf("Enter size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter elements in array : ");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    /* Input element position to delete */
    printf("Enter the element position to delete : ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    /* If delete position is invalid */
    if(pos==size+1 || pos<0)
    {
        printf("Invalid position! Please enter position between 1 to %d", size);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Copy next element value to current element */
        for(i=pos-1; i<size-1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }

        /* Decrement array size by 1 */
        size--;
    }

    /* Print array after deletion */
    printf("\nElements of array after delete are : ");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the input `size` is > 100? Better to add a check on `size` input if you use fixed size array in your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize the array then:

- if it is an automatic variable (declared inside a function) it will have garbage;
- if it is a global variable, it will be zero.

To "delete" an element from the array you have to:

- keep track of how many valid elements there are using a variable (initialily 3);
- move all higher elements one place down and decrement the number of valid elements (so now it says 2).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code,this code can delete any position in code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
 int i, size, pos,j;

//  array size
printf("Enter size of the array : ");
scanf("%d", &size);

int array[size];



for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("Enter element %d : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

//position to delete 
printf("Enter position to delete : ");
scanf("%d", &pos);

//invalid position
if(pos>=size || pos<0)
{
    printf("Invalid position! Please enter position between 0 to %d", size);
}
else
{


    j=0;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(pos==i){
            continue;
        }
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        j++;
    }

    //Decrement size
    size--;
}

// Print array 
printf("\nElements of array after delete are : ");
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
}

return 0;
 }
```